# No sound on Dell Inspiron 6400n

Tags: 12.04, sound, dell, intel

After a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Inspiron 6400n Laptop there is no sound on any application I use apart from the log in screen ready noise.
If I click on the speaker icon on the top panel then sound settings it tells me that the default playback device is S/PDIF. In alsamixer the slider is set to zero.
I am sure it should be HDA intel or similar.
How can I get the sound working please...?

Answer (score 0):

I removed `alsa-hda-dkms` (`alsa-hda-dkms 0.201205021650~precise1`) and rebooted. Sound is back.

Comment: So you went, sudo apt-get remove alsa-hda-dkms? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

i met this problem before,  after update.. Try this may help:

open **terminal** and then edit

```
sudo cat /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

`#Set to yes to start system wide Speech Dispatcher`

```
RUN=no
```